# pagination within a $_POST 'submit'

Tags: php, forms, pagination, submit

when i choose a category and hit the submit button my pagination shows the correct amount of pages needed for the amount of records my SQL statment has retrieved. however when i click page 2 for example the page refreshes and the data is not shown anymore instead of showing the next page it just returns to show the category drop down box and the search button.

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

  $filmCategory = isset($_REQUEST['filmCategory']) ? $_REQUEST['filmCategory'] : null;

  if (empty($filmCategory)) {
    $whereclause = '';
  }else {
    $whereclause = "where c.category_id = '$filmCategory'";
  }

  require_once('functions.php');

//user input
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
    $perPage = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <=15 ? (int)$_GET['per_page'] : 10;

 //positioning
$start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;

//query 
  $filmSQL =  $db->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  f.title, f.description, f.release_year, c.name,
                   f.rating, f.last_update
            from nfc_film f
            inner join nfc_film_category fc
            on f.film_id = fc.film_id
            inner join nfc_category c
            on fc.category_id = c.category_id
            $whereclause
            LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}");

// execute the query and get the title, description, release year, name, rating and last update of film
  $filmSQL->execute();

//echo the table with the titles and correct data from SQL
  echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
  echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Release Year</th><th>Category</th><th>Rating</th><th>Last Update</th></tr>";

  while ($filmInfo = $filmSQL->fetchObject()) {

    $upperLower= upperFirst(lowercase($filmInfo->title));
      $uLDescription= firstUpper(lowercase($filmInfo->description));
      $noChar = substr($uLDescription,0,100).'...';
      echo "<form action='filmInfo.php' method='get'>";
    echo "<tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='filmInfo' value='{$upperLower}'</td>
            <td><p>$noChar.</p></td>
            <td>{$filmInfo->release_year}</td>
            <td>{$filmInfo->name}</td>
            <td>{$filmInfo->rating}</td>
            <td>{$filmInfo->last_update}</td>
            <td><input type='submit' value='Film Details' </td>
          </tr>";
    echo" </form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";;
```

so everything above works fine but then when i choose page 2 for example the page refreshes and all data disappears

```
    $total = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total")->fetch()['total'];
//use CEIL to round up the pages so here are no pages with decimals
    $pages = ceil($total / $perPage);

    for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++):;
    echo"<div id='pagination'>

                <a href='?page=$x'>$x</a>

            </div>";
    endfor;
}
?>
```

i want it to show the next page of records but i cant get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Should be,

```
//positioning
$start = isset($_GET['page']) && (int)$_GET['page'] > 1 ? ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $perPage : 0;
```

Comment: that hasnt worked either the pagination its self isnt the issue it brings forth the right amount of records i have asked and shows the page numbers however when i click on the links if(isset($_POST['search'])) { resets and no recorsd show thanks anyway